# Perl FTP zero size file

Tags: perl

In Perl, I tried to ftp a file, but the file In the remote server is zero size.

```
$ftp = new Net::FTP($URL);
$ftp->put($local_file, $remote_file);
```

I am sure that the local file is not empty, but why is the ftp-ed file empty?

Answer (score 4):

Did you check the docs?
http://search.cpan.org/dist/libnet/Net/FTP.pm
Specifically, you need to login, even if you're connecting anonymously, and you should check the return code of every code.
Here's the synopsis from the CPAN page:

```
use Net::FTP;

$ftp = Net::FTP->new("some.host.name", Debug => 0)
  or die "Cannot connect to some.host.name: $@";

$ftp->login("anonymous",'-anonymous@')
  or die "Cannot login ", $ftp->message;

$ftp->cwd("/pub")
  or die "Cannot change working directory ", $ftp->message;

$ftp->get("that.file")
  or die "get failed ", $ftp->message;

$ftp->quit;
```

Comment: login is not an issue. File was ftp-ed to the server, the only issue is, size is zero

Comment: @user595234, The rest of the advice (check what error you got) still applies.

Answer (score 0):

To find out what problem you are experiencing, please modify your code as follows:

```
$ftp = new Net::FTP($URL); 
$ftp->put($local_file, $remote_file) or die $ftp->message;
```

Most likely this modification will give you enough information to solve the problem.

Comment: thanks. I found the reason. I didn't close the file handler before ftp. but at least it should give me some error instead of zero size

Comment: @user595234 - Great. Would be nice to get some upvote and acceptance from you, if you feel I helped you. Thanks.